# Send values of ng-model to angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I have four different inputs and want to send value of changed input to controller without pressing send button or whatever.

How i got it all inputs should to have next syntaxis.

```
<input ng-model="borderRadius" ng-change="change()">
<input ng-model="background" ng-change="change()">
```

Or not?

I want to get them in my app.js

```
control.controller('generatorOptions', function ($scope) {

  $scope.buttonStyle = {
    "border-radius" : " -- here is value of it -- ",
    "background" : " -- here is value of it -- "
  };

});
```

Update: That is working just fine, but how can i optimise code? https://github.com/tanotify/Button-style-generator/blob/master/public/assets/scripts.min.js

Comment: `ng-model` already creates scope property, just assign button properties to each `ng-model`

Comment: Is it right to create it this way? https://github.com/tanotify/Button-style-generator/blob/master/public/assets/scripts.min.js

Comment: this should be working as is. the link you provided... would  be better if you put comments around explaining what is expected from each block of code... otherwise its hard to give relevant comments

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define in your controller:

```
control.controller('generatorOptions', function ($scope) {
  $scope.buttonStyle={};


  $scope.change = function() {
     console.log("borderRadius value:"+$scope.buttonStyle.borderRadius);
     console.log("background value:"+$scope.buttonStyle.background);
  };

});
```

This is your view:

```
<input ng-model="buttonStyle.borderRadius" ng-change="change()">
<input ng-model="buttonStyle.background" ng-change="change()">
```

It means, that first you need define object(buttonStyle) in you controller, than this object is accesseble in you view and in view you will define new properties(radius and background) of your object which you can access in controller by object.